# Put on a geojson on the MapboxGeocoder result

Tags: maps, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I want to make a map with a Mapbox Style and the MapboxGeocoder searchbox (the user type the location and the map put the map's center on that location) -this is solved-. But also, I want to put on that center a external source (geojson) with the drawing of a polygon.
In short, I want the user to search for a location, the map puts it in the center and, in addition, the geojson polygon is placed on that center (to make a comparison).
Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Encarni.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the coordinates for where to center the map, you need to:

- **Translate** the coordinates of your geojson polygon so it will be centered over the center of the map. There is a turf method called `transformTranslate` that can help, but you need to know the distance and direction: http://turfjs.org/docs/#transformTranslate
- To calculate the distance and direction, you can use turf's `distance` and `bearing` methods using the starting center point of the polygon and the target center point.
- Once you have the translated geojson in hand, use `map.setData()` to assign the data to a source in your map (assumes you already have a source and layer on the map to display this polygon)

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I'll try it, but I'm afraid that what you explain is too complicated for my level 